# How do I find out which key is pressed, when it's a non standard key, absent on the majority of keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

My ASUS G553Q whatever has a Microphone Mute key, which doesn't function correctly anymore. I want to use AHK to intercept the key and replace it with F24, which I'll bind to mute in discord, the issue is, how I find out which key that is? it's not on any online keyboard tester

Comment: See  [Special Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Comment: uh, that didn't get me any closer

Comment: Did you add [#InstallKeybdHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_InstallKeybdHook.htm) to your script? What did [KeyHistory](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/KeyHistory.htm) show after you had pressed and released the key?

Comment: I have basically zero clue how to use AHK, but, the key does not show up in KeyHistory

Comment: If it does not show up in `KeyHistory` even after using `#InstallKeybdHook`, then you're going to have a much more difficult time. You should be able to at least intercept the input by running this script [RawInputList.ahk](https://gist.github.com/TheZoc/4bf163aa9a9922b21fbf) and then hitting Capture. You can check out the following thread for more info on it and how to use the information it outputs to create a hotkey, but be warned that it's rather advanced: https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/36304-hidextended-input-devices-ms-natural-keyboard-4000-etc/